# Problema com String.Split

Tags: c#, array, vb.net

O Meu problema é o seguinte: Quero obter diferentes objetos de uma *string*, dividindo elas pelo caractere `;`, exceto as que tiver entre parêntesis.

Exemplo:

```
Linha1;
Linha2;
L i n h a 3;
(linha que não quero que apareça; outra; mais uma;)
Linha 4;
```

E está saindo assim na *array*:

```
Lista1, Linha2, L i n h a 3, linha que não quero que apareça, outra, mais uma, linha 4
```

Mas não quero que: *linha que não quero que apareça", a "outra" ou a "mais uma* seja inclusa nessa *array*, ou resumindo: **não quero que nada que esteja entre parêntesis seja incluso na lista**.

### Atualização

Ninguém está conseguindo entender o que eu quero, aqui vai um exemplo do meu código na minha linguagem:

```
{
  echo "Olá, mundo!";
  echo "Aqui é outro bloco!";
  def MeuTeste = "24055";
  if 123 = 123 (echo "Executa isso!"; echo "isso também!";);
  if 123 = 545 (echo "Não execute isso!"; echo "ignore isso!";);
  pause;
}
```

Aqui está a estrutura que separa cada `statement` pelo caractere `;`:

```
For currentStatement As Integer = 0 To Statements.Split(Separator).Length - 1
     Dim currentIndex As String() = Statements.Split(";"c)
     Dim currentText As String = currentIndex(currentStatement) 
     .... comandos que executam o currentText
```

O Correto era retornar os valores dessa variável `currentIndex`:

```
echo "Olá, mundo!"
echo "Aqui é outro bloco!"
def MeuTeste = "24055"
if 123 = 123 (echo "Executa isso!"; echo "isso também!";)
if 123 = 545 (echo "Não execute isso!"; echo "ignore isso!";)
pause
```

mas ai ta o problema, e retorna desse jeito:

```
echo "Olá, mundo!"
echo "Aqui é outro bloco!"
def MeuTeste = "24055"
if 123 = 123 (echo "Executa isso!"
echo "isso também!"
)
if 123 = 545 (echo "Não execute isso!"
echo "ignore isso!"
)
pause
```

Moral da história, ele **separa tudo que estiver entre os parênteses** e a minha pergunta é essa: *Como eu não separo o que estiver dentro dos parênteses?, de qualquer jeito, não quero que exclui o que esta nos parênteses, e sim apenas não separar cada coisa pelo caractere `;`*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a expressão [`;(?!.*\)|\()`](https://regex101.com/r/sF3sS4/1) para dividir o texto usando como delimitador `;`, o que estiver entre parênteses será ignorado.

```
public static void Main() {
    string codigo = 
    @"echo ""Olá, mundo!"";
echo ""Aqui é outro bloco!"";
def MeuTeste = ""24055"";
if 123 = 123 (echo ""Executa isso!""; echo ""isso também!"";);
if 123 = 545 (echo ""Não execute isso!""; echo ""ignore isso!"";);
pause;";

     var linhas = Regex.Split(codigo, @";(?!.*\)|\()");
     foreach (var linha in linhas) {
          Console.Write(linha);
          // echo "Olá, mundo!"
          // echo "Aqui é outro bloco!"
          // def MeuTeste = "24055"
          // if 123 = 123 (echo "Executa isso!"; echo "isso também!";)
          // if 123 = 545 (echo "Não execute isso!"; echo "ignore isso!";)
          // pause
     }
     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[Ver **`demonstração`**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mAyWee)

Comment: Não funcionou pelo simples motivo: Ele simplesmente remove tudo que está entre (...), não quero que remove, apenas não inclua no texto... Pois como por exemplo, no meu compilador cada comando é separado pelo caractere ";", no bloco "if" ele é mais ou menos assim: `if expressão = outra expressão (statements; segundo;)` e está removendo o conteúdo do Bloco IF, se eu usar o `String.Split` original, será separado o que está dentro do bloco.

Comment: Editei minha postagem, espero que entenda o que realmente quero.

Comment: @CypherPotato Editei a resposta. Quando eu tiver tempo, se você quiser, posto em VB. NET.

Comment: Vou tentar aqui...

Comment: Valeu fera! Era isso mesmo, de coração mesmo, tu é de Deus cara ^-^

Comment: Achei um bug... o sinal de mais `+` é removido na array... isso é normal?

Comment: @CypherPotato ^.^  não é normal não. A *regex* `;(?!.*\)|\()` não excluiria ele..

Comment: Ah achei o erro, tava na codificação, tava ANSII :P

Comment: Eeeeh, achei um bug aqui... https://dotnetfiddle.net/PHkWo4 ele não tem suporte para multi linhas?

Comment: Consegui, substitui aquela regex por essa: `;(?!((.|\n)*)\)|\()` e funcionou.

Answer (score 3):

O método `String.split` aceita uma `expressão regular` não apenas um caractere.

Moral da história, você precisa de uma expressão regular que ignore caracteres dentro de ()

A expressão será esta:

**(;|\(.*\))**

Experimente isso:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Linha1;Linha2;L i n h a 3;(linha que não quero que apareça; outra; mais uma;)Linha 4;";

    String[] parts = str.split("(;|\\(.*\\))");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
}
```

Não é isso ainda?

então use este site e contrua suas expressões regulares:

http://www.regexr.com/

Para plataforma .Net na linguagem Visual Basic, a lógica é a mesma e a expressão regular, tb, contudo, considere esse link de referencia para implementar:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Em BASIC (Visual Basic) seria a mesma expressão?

Comment: A expressão regular é  a mesma, uma expressão regular é uma linguagem de domínio específico, o que muda para Visual Basic, é que vc deve usar: Regex.Split (String, String);
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

vou adicionar este comentário a resposta tb.

Comment: Filipe, posso estar errado mas, tem certeza de que está [*regex*](http://www.regexr.com/3b5i3) funciona? pois ela está *casando* inclusive dentro do parenteses. Na pergunta o Cypher tinha por preferência as linguagens C# e Vb. NET, o [teu código é em Java](http://ideone.com/GFohWY).

Comment: O que acontece é que a Expressão Regular é também uma LInguagem, mas não de programação, e sim é tida como um Domain Specific Language.
Há uma referência na minha resposta para um código em Visual Basic. As linguagens são apenas motores, este Sistema Web sempre funcionou pra mim. 
E sim, esta expressão regular funciona sim: (;|\\(.*\\))

É que em Java, temos que colocar mais uma barra como caractere de Escape, assim sendo na verdade a expressão é essa:
(;|\(.*\))
Vou atualizar a resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: @FilipeGonzagaMiranda A tua [**regex**](http://www.regexr.com/3b5i6) ainda **não funciona**, nem em [**Java**](http://ideone.com/5sq3Dr), nem em [**C#**](http://ideone.com/wYjerT). Quando for se referir a alguém, use o `@` na frente.

Comment: Perdão, fiz uma confusão @qmechanik 
A expressão é essa (;|\\(.*\\))

Comment: @qmechanik
A engine do Stack overflow está apagando a barra.... rsrs - Foi bom que aprendi
(;|\\(.*\\))
Mesma lógica do Java... usei duas aqui, mas vc vai ver só uma agora

Comment: @FilipeGonzagaMiranda No Java a expressão `(;|\(.*\))` [**funciona**](http://ideone.com/5sq3Dr)!, porém no [**.NET não**](http://ideone.com/R3yklJ). =/ talvez sejam *engines* diferentes, não tenho certeza.

Comment: @FilipeGonzagaMiranda Se possível deixe explicito na resposta que a expressão `(;|\(.*\))` não funciona no **.NET**.

Comment: Bom, eu ainda não testei na realidade, eu ainda não to com o projeto aqui comigo, testarei ainda hoje e irei passar a resposta.

Comment: Bom, já que esse regex ai não funciona, como seria ele em **.NET**?